# JavaScript: "missing ;" or "unexpected token JavaScript }"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to debug a simple code and kind of scratching my head. I've copied a code from Internet, where checkboxs are working as radio button.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="priorityHigh" id="priorityHigh" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('priorityLow').checked=false;}"> VLACP Short
<input type="checkbox" name="priorityLow" id="priorityLow" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('priorityHigh').checked=false;}">VLACP Long
```

This above code works fine when I'm testing in a simple new page.

But when I incorporated this code into my main code, where if user select tagAll, it call a function optionCheck() shown below.

```
function optionCheck(){

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var option = document.getElementById("tagid_"+k ).value;

    if(option == "tagAll"){
        div.innerHTML ='<input type="checkbox" name="priorityHigh" id="priorityHigh" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById("priorityLow").checked=false;}"> VLACP Short<input type="checkbox" name="priorityLow" id="priorityLow" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.getElementById("priorityHigh").checked=false;}">VLACP Long';
        document.getElementById('tag').appendChild(div);
    }
    if(option == "untagAll"){
        div.innerHTML ='STP Fast:<input type="checkbox" name="stpfast_" value="stpfast" id = "stpfast_' + k + '"checked>&nbsp; SLPP Gaurd:<input type="checkbox" name="slppgaurd" value="slppgaurd" id = "slppgaurd_' + k + '" checked>';
        document.getElementById('tag').appendChild(div);
    }
    if(option == "UnTagPvid"){
        window.location = "http://google.com";
    }

}
```

Now if I run this code it complain about "unexpected token JavaScript }", after debuging I realized that problem is with the use of double quote and I fixed that as shown below:

```
 div.innerHTML ='<input type="checkbox" name="priorityHigh" id="priorityHigh" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('priorityLow').checked=false;}"> VLACP Short
<input type="checkbox" name="priorityLow" id="priorityLow" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.getElementById('priorityHigh').checked=false;}">VLACP Long';
```

Now, am facing a weird error saying `SyntaxError: missing; before statement` on the above line on coloumn 132.

Comment: `This above code works fine when I'm testing in a simple new page` - surprising since the onclick code for `id="priorityLow"` is invalid

Comment: You are missing `)` in `if(this.checked{document.getElementById('priorityHigh').checked=false;}`

Comment: And you need to escape the quotes when using same quote inside it.

Comment: @Tushar.  yeh once I did that ..."unexpected token javascript }"  error is fixed now am getting "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" on the above line on coloumn 132.

Comment: There could hard be any better example of why not to construct huge strings of HTML in the way you are doing. Find some other approach--such as building the DOM using DOM APIs, or using a templating language, or at an absolute minimum breaking up your string building into individual lines adding one piece at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems. First, remove the "enter" after VLACP Short. Second, concatenate strings correctly (add escape character, backslash, where needed):

```
// Example 1
div.innerHTML ='<input type="checkbox" name="priorityHigh" id="priorityHigh" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById(\'priorityLow\').checked=false;}"> VLACP Short <input type="checkbox" name="priorityLow" id="priorityLow" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.getElementById(\'priorityHigh\').checked=false;}">VLACP Long';

// Example 2
div.innerHTML ='<input type="checkbox" name="priorityHigh" id="priorityHigh" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById(\'priorityLow\').checked=false;}"> VLACP Short'
   + '<input type="checkbox" name="priorityLow" id="priorityLow" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.getElementById(\'priorityHigh\').checked=false;}">VLACP Long';
```

Comment: You are the man ......thanks a lot Allan ...this really help.. I really wish ....the IE or Chrome debugger were smart enough to tell me ...